# Source for story about origins of Chayei Adam

Tags: chabad, vilna-gaon, story-identification

I recently heard a story that when the Vilna Gaon found out that the Alter Rebbe made his own Shulchan Aruch (Shulchan Aruch HaRav), he told his relative (through marriage) Rav Avraham Danzig to write his own similar work, which was the impetus to write his Chayei Adam.

This story sounds sketchy, and the person who said it over wasn't sure if it was true. Is this story recorded anywhere?

Comment: quasi-related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81076/1739